# Joint Distribution Implies Independence...?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Consider the measurable space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ and a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.  Define a finite sequence of random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.  Each $X_i$ induces a probability distribution measure on $\mathcal{B}$ given by $\mu_i(B_i) = P(X_i^{-1}(B_i))$ for $B_i \in \mathcal{B}$.  This part is clear to me.

Now place these random variables into a vector, $X = (X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ and consider the target space $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B} \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathcal{B})$.

Here's one part I'm not sure about.  We now have $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$, and I guess since each $X_i$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable we get that $X$ is somehow $\mathcal{F}$-measurable and so we may define a "joint" probability distribution measure on $\mathcal{B} \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathcal{B}$ given by $\mu(B) = P(X^{-1}(B))$ for $B = B_1 \times \ldots \times B_n \in \mathcal{B} \otimes \cdots \otimes \mathcal{B}$.

However, as I understand, a measure on a product space is called a product measure and is defined such that $\mu(B) = \mu_1(B_1)\cdots \mu_n(B_n)$.  But then $P(X^{-1}(B)) = P(X_1^{-1}(B_1))\cdots P(X_n^{-1}(B_n))$ and so the random variables are independent automatically.

I've clearly misunderstood and/or overlooked something, so I would appreciate my errors being pointed out!

Comment: A measure defined on a product of measurable spaces does not have to be a product measure, as Michael Hardy has pointed out. However, in this case, you can check that $P^X$ will indeed be the product of the individual measures $P^{X_i}$ **if and only if** the $X_i$ are independent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A measure on a product space need not be a product measure.  Suppose
$$
X = \left. \begin{cases} 0 & \text{with probability }1/4, \\  1 & \text{with probability }3/4, \end{cases} \right\}\text{ and }Y = \left. \begin{cases} 0 & \text{with probability }1/3, \\  1 & \text{with probability }2/3. \end{cases} \right\} \tag 1
$$
The following two **marginal distributions** are consistent with infinitely many **joint distributions** only one of which is the **product measure**, which is the measure for which the two random variables are independent:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
& X=0 & X=1 \\
\hline Y=0 & 3/12 & 1/12 \\  \hline Y=1 & 0/12 & 8/12 \\  \hline 
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
& X=0 & X=1 \\
\hline Y=0 & 0/12 & 4/12 \\  \hline Y=1 & 3/12 & 5/12 \\  \hline 
\end{array}
$$

- Both of the joint distributions displayed in these two tables result in the two marginal distributions given in $(1)$.
- In both of these two joint distributions, $X$ and $Y$ fail to be independent.
- Every joint distribution consistent with the two marginal distributions is a weighted average, or convex combination, of these two.
- In only one of those joint distributions, $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  That one is the product measure.  (That one is $1/3$ of the first one plus $2/3$ of the second.)